# Multiple MySQL Tables in one query

Tags: mysql

So, I am trying to query multiple tables.

This is what I have so far, :

```
SELECT * FROM patientdetails  
WHERE DATEDIFF( CURRENT_DATE, DOB ) /365 <18 
and Gender='Male'  
AND RAMQ in 
(
   SELECT `RAMQ` 
   FROM `pathology` 
   WHERE `Result`='positive'
)
```

This works just fine, but I need to compare the date to a date field in another table, I have have tried many different solutions.

Solution 1:

```
SELECT * FROM patientdetails  
WHERE DATEDIFF( pathology.Date, DOB ) /365 <18 
and Gender='Male'  
AND RAMQ in 
(
   SELECT `RAMQ`  
   FROM `pathology` 
   WHERE `Result`='positive'
)
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT * FROM patientdetails p, pathology pp  
WHERE DATEDIFF( pp.Date, p.DOB ) /365 <18 
and p.Gender='Male'  
AND p.RAMQ in 
(
   SELECT `RAMQ` 
   FROM `pathology` 
   WHERE `Result`='positive'
)
```

None of these seem to work, and its quite frustrating. If someone could provide me with some guidance, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` them this way:

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM patientdetails  AS d
INNER JOIN pathology AS p ON d.RAMQ = p.RAMQ
WHERE DATEDIFF(p.Date, d.DOB ) /365 < 18 
  AND d.Gender='Male'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for, I understand what a join is now.

Answer (score 0):

Can we start with this...

```
SELECT * 
  FROM patientdetails pd 
  JOIN pathology g
    ON g.RAMQ = pd.RAMQ 
   AND g.Result = 'positive'
 WHERE pd.DOB > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 18 YEAR 
   AND pd.Gender='Male';
```

...?